# Objects representing worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

It seems to me that normally objects representing worksheets are `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc. And `Sheet1.Name` returns its name which could be modified either in Excel or VBA.

However, I see in the following workbook `database_GEV_V_2_3.xls`, the objects are `Foglio1`, `Foglio2`... And `Foglio1.Name` returns `Home`... Coud anyone tell me how this is possible? What did they do to name the sheet objects this way?

[image]

**Edit1:**
Here is the available menu...

[image]

Comment: select, say, `Foglio1 (Home)`, open `Properties Window` (press F4 for Windows) and change `Name` property

Comment: After the selection, I don't see `Properties Window` (I use Mac)... I attached all the possibilities to my OP...

Comment: try to select menu `VIEW` (on menu bar) and select `Properties Window`, and then choose sheet

Comment: I see, thank you... Do you know how to manage that in VBA? I mean, getting or changing this name via VBA?

Comment: try this one: `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Foglio1").Name = "newName"`

Comment: FYI, these are `Codename`s and can be referred to as such in code, e.g., `MyWorksheet.Codename`. You can also use them to refer to sheets directly if your VBA is in the same workbook, e.g, `Foglio1.Range("A1").Value = "SoftTimur"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you can change it manually:

- Goto `VIEW`-->`Properties Window` on menu bar (for Windows you can also press <kbd>F4</kbd>).
- Select any sheet and change its `Name` property on `Properties Window`

How to change it programmatically:

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Foglio1").Name = "newName"
```

where `"Foglio1"` is old name and `"newName"` is new name.